# How to query data from Uniswap using the JS SDK?

Tags: dapps, exchanges, uniswap, decentralized-exchange

I'm having problems retrieving some data metrics using the Uniswap JS SDK.
When I try to query **getInputAmount** it returns this error:

```
(node:88) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined
    at Pair.involvesToken (/mnt/c/Users/Joe/node_modules/@uniswap/sdk/dist/sdk.cjs.development.js:790:18)
    at Pair.getInputAmount (/mnt/c/Users/Joe/node_modules/@uniswap/sdk/dist/sdk.cjs.development.js:837:11)
    at init (/mnt/c/Users/Joe/Desktop/JStest/myScripts/TEST.js:8:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:88) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or 
by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:88) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the JS code I'm running:

```
const { ChainId, Token, WETH, Fetcher } = require('@uniswap/sdk')  

const DAI = new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F', 18)  

const init = async () => {     
    const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(DAI, WETH[DAI.chainId])
    const amount = await pair.getInputAmount('1000000000000000000');
    console.log(amount);
}  

init();
```

I would really appreciate your guidance on how to proceed!

Answer (score 1):

Parameter of `getInputAmount` or `getOutputAmount` is value of type `TokenAmount` (not string as you provided).

```
import { TokenAmount } from '@uniswap/sdk'
...
const daiAmount = new TokenAmount(DAI /* or another token */, '1000000000000000000')
const inputAmount = await pair.getInputAmount(daiAmount);
```